# "DisplayMetrics cannot be resolved to a type" Eclipse error

Tags: java, android, dpi

I'm working on an android game(in libgdx) and I have a problem: I need to get device's dpi for better playing experience. So I tried using DisplayMetrics.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int densitiy = displaymetrics.densityDpi;
```

The code above gives me following errors:

> DisplayMetrics cannot be resolved to a type
>
> DisplayMetrics cannot be resolved to a type
>
> The method getWindowManager() is undefined for the type GameScreen

I have no idea what to do with it :/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What class is this in? `GameScreen` is not an `Activity` nor is it a `Context` in general, that would not be cross-platform. This needs to be in your android-specific code with the interfaces and all that going on.

Answer (score 1):

> DisplayMetrics cannot be resolved to a type

you didn't import it, or you did import the wrong one. You should add

```
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
```

to the import list of your class

> getWindowManager() is undefined for the type GameScreen

is a method of `Context`. If `GameScreen` is subclass of Fragment you can use `getActivity()` to access it. If it is subclass of View you can use `getContext()`. Otherwise you need to provide a Context object to `GameScreen`

Comment: When I try to import Display Metrics I get this error: `The import android cannot be resolved`.

And how exactly do I use getActivity() in this case? Sorry, I'm into Java for a couple of months, I don't get it all yet :(